# The file is not available right after it is uploaded to aws s3

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When I try to get a file after it was uploaded to s3 it returns 404 error (part of the code is below)

```
const file = Buffer.from([]); // some file data here
const bucketName = 'bucket-name';
const fileName = 'test.json';
 await this.s3Client.putObject({
            Body: file,
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Key: fileName,
        }).promise();
await this.s3Client.headObject({
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Key: fileName,}).promise();  // -> returns 404 error, but if set some delay (1000 ms) between getObject and headObject it works well
```

Is there a way to be sure the file is available without using delays?

Comment: Why do you not trust the s3?

Comment: @Konrad It is not a question of trust, I have a flow that requires such behavior

Comment: this happened with S3 because of eventual consistency, known issue, we have faced. it's takes time to get metadata after uploading the file into S3. workaround, put some retry logic.

Comment: S3 is now strongly consistent ([Amazon S3 Update – Strong Read-After-Write Consistency | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-update-strong-read-after-write-consistency/)) but it seems there can still be a delay.